# AWS Codebuild Ruby 2.6.5 runtime missing on Amazon Linux Standard 3.0 image

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I have a ruby project and I am trying to build via AWS codedeploy and having some issues specifying the ruby version. I am using Ruby 2.6.5 and I am using AWS Codedeploy standard image (aws/codebuild/standard:2.0) because according to the [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/al2/x86_64/standard/2.0/Dockerfile#L320) it supports Ruby 2.6.5. `.ruby-version` has 2.6.5. I also attempted a build where I put "runtime-versions: ruby: 2.6.5" in the buildspec but that threw the following error: "Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named '2.6.5' of ruby. This build image has the following versions: 2.6". This is my buildspec.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      ruby: 2.6.5
    commands:
      - echo Installing Bundler...
      - gem install bundler -v 2.2.27
      - bundle install
  build:
    commands:
       - bundle exec rspec
```

I also tried using `aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0-20.03.13` image version from AL Standard 3.0 image instead of the latest but I get the same error while on github I see ruby version 2.6.5 has been added https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/tree/20.03.13.
I also tried Ubuntu Standard 5.0 and same thing.
What am I missing?

Comment: I am in a similar situation with 2.7 and 2.7.4. If you have found a better way to do this other than installing the required version, please post it here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation like this and I couldn't find any other solution than installing the required version inside buildspec file

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      ruby: 2.6
    commands:
      - echo Installing app dependencies...
      - rbenv install 2.6.5 && rbenv global 2.6.5
      - bundle install
```

This might increase your build time, since it has to pull the required version

Comment: That should work. An alternative would be to use an official jenkins docker container and run it as an ECS task in EC2 mode (use spot instance) and use amazon-ecs Jenkins plugin to run your jobs in a separate docker containers in Fargate mode. But that really depends on your current setup and cost possibilities

Comment: You could also build your own image based on Amazon Linux 2 with docker and docker-compose installed and store it in ECR or Docker Hub and use it as your custom image and in the buildspec run docker and docker-compose commands to build your image and run docker-compose services. This eliminates the need to worry about your ruby version.